# In procmail, how can I manipulate a subject line with two MATCH variables?

Tags: email, procmail

I am succeeding rewriting my subject line to have a [LIST] prepended to it:

```
:0fhw
* ^TO_[^<>@ ]+@example\.com\>
* ^Subject:\/.+
| /usr/local/bin/formail -I"Subject: [LIST]$MATCH"
```

This succeeds and turns:

```
Subject: here is the subject line
```

into

```
Subject: [LIST] here is the subject line
```

ButeI also want to insert the user portion of `user@example.com` into the subject line, like this:

```
Subject: [LIST] user@example.com here is the subject line
```

... and I don't understand how to do this when I only get one `$MATCH` variable!

How can I insert two different variables into the single `formail` line that rewrites the subject line?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, the answer is simple: Copy `$MATCH` to another variable. The implementation will still be a bit scruffy because indeed you only get one `MATCH` per recipe. The workaround is to use nested recipes.

```
:0
* ^Subject:\/.+
{
    subj=$MATCH
    :0
    * ^TO_\/[^<>@ ]+@example\.com\>
    {
        user=$MATCH
        :0fhw
        * user ?? ()\/.+@example\.com
        | formail -I"Subject: [LIST] $MATCH $subj"
    }
}
```

The innermost recipe is to trim off the `\>` match from the end of the captured `user` variable; if including it in the Subject: line is acceptable, this can obviously be simplified.

Probably take care to include `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH` so you don't have to hardcode the full path to `formail`. Hardcoding it also makes it impossible to override it for debugging purposes.